# Android fragment, remove one of many

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem of managing fragments. (Using Support Package, revision 9 (June 2012))

I have an activity with 2 fragments on the screen.  If I add fragment A, then add Fragment B, then destroy fragment A Fragment B is also destroyed.

I'm managing fragments this way (there is the begin and commit lines)

**add**

```
ft.add(location, fragment, tag);
ft.addToBackStack(tag);
```

**Remove**

```
this.mFragmentManager.popBackStack(this.fragmentTopBarType.toString(),
                    FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
ft.remove(fragment);
```

This works quite well, my back stack gets cleaned, bar this little quirk.  I've no idea how I can simply remove a single fragment from the backstack, as popping the backstack removes everything below that fragment.  Any ideas or am I'm just being thick?